# Including source files from a repo in HUGO posts

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm setting up a blog with [HUGO](https://gohugo.io/), as a commented code repo, and I'm including source files right from the repos on the posts.

I've been able to get it to a working condition and want to improve it but I'm stuck.

### What I've done

There's a .gitignore'd **repos** dir inside the HUGO site root, that holds the source code repos.

There's a **getSourceFile.html** shortcode:

```
{{ with .Get 0 }}
<pre><code>{{ readFile . }}</code>
<span class="source-footer">{{.}}</span>
</pre>
{{ end }}
```

Then, in the post I can use the shortcode like so:

```
#### Base/EntityTypeConfiguration.cs

Estas clases permiten manejar una clase de configuración por cada clase del modelo...

{{< getSourceFile "repos/EFCoreApp/src/EFCore.App/Base/EntityTypeConfiguration.cs" >}}
```

and I get this:

[image]

Which is pretty nice, since I don't have to copy and paste code, it's 100% up to date and I am sure it compiles.

But this is where I'm stuck!

### What I would like to do

1) Setting up the repo root in the front matter so the shortcode is simpler to use, like so:

```
{{< getSourceFile "src/EFCore.App/Base/EntityTypeConfiguration.cs" >}}
```

2) Being able to pass the language as a parameter to the shortcode to use it in the highlighting feature, something like so (this does not work):

```
{{< getSourceFile "src/EFCore.App/Base/EntityTypeConfiguration.cs" "csharp" >}}
```

**getSourceFile.html**:

````
{{ with .Get 0 }}
```{{.Get 1}}
<pre><code>{{ readFile . }}</code>
<span class="source-footer">{{.}}</span>
</pre>
```
{{ end }}
````

Or better yet, infer it from the file extension! ;-)

I think it shouldn't be too difficult but this is my first experience with Hugo, Go and the Templates, so, Could someone help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer in [HUGO's dicussion forum](https://discuss.gohugo.io/t/including-source-files-from-a-repo-in-hugo-posts/5683/4), so I just wanted to post it here to finish the question.

This is the final shortcode:

```
{{ $file := .Get 0 }}
{{ $repoFilePath := printf "%s/%s" $.Page.Params.reponame $file }}
{{ $repoFile := printf "repos/%s" $repoFilePath }}
{{ $fileExt := replace (index (findRE "(\\.)\\w+$" $file) 0) "." "" }}
<pre><code class="language-{{ $fileExt }}">{{ readFile $repoFile }}</code>
<span class="source-footer">{{ $repoFilePath }}</span>
</pre>
```

And this even solves the language highlighting from the file extension.